# How to solve this logarithmic equation: $8n^2 = 64n\log_{\ 2}(n)$?

Tags: logarithms

I want to solve this equation: $$8n^2 = 64n\log_{\ 2}(n)$$

After some steps, I get to a point in which I believe, the only way to proceed is to apply something like Bolzano's or Newton's method to find a solution.

I get to: $n = 8\log_{\ 2}(n)$

Of course with big numbers applying Bolzano would be very tedious and this is why I want to ask you if there is an analytical way of solving this, not by approximations.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry, numerical methods only.

Comment: You could use the Lambert W function and its branches to get a closed form

Answer (score 2):

No analytical solution exists in terms of elementary functions. However, simplifying the expression is advisable before running Newton's Method, if it is practical to simplify. Solution would be:
$$x_{i+1}=x_i-\frac{8log_2(n)-n}{\frac{1}{n*ln(2)}-1}$$
$$x_0=1.000$$
$$x_1=3.259$$
$$x_2=21.877$$
$$x_3=36.581$$
$$x_4=41.748$$
$$x_5=43.116$$
$$x_6=43.453$$
$$x_7=43.534$$
$$x_8=43.553$$
$$x_9=43.558$$
$$x_{10}=43.559$$
$$x_{11}=43.559$$
As you can see, the function takes a long time to converge, but it does converge nonetheless.

Comment: How about the other solution, an approximation of which is $1.0999970302376094010$?